# How to save the json string using afnetworking

Tags: ios

How can I save the JSON String returned by the C#.net Web Service using Afnetworking?

In .net returning works like this:
`string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ls);`

where `ls` is a list of class objects. I want to save it as `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`

The request is in SOAP Format.

My Response object has the following Format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <checkloginOrnotResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
             <checkloginOrnotResult>
                 [{"loginstatus":"No", 
                 "userprofileid":null, 
                 "username":null, 
                 "usercompname":null,
                 "mailverified":false,
                 "ststusid":30}]
            </checkloginOrnotResult>
        </checkloginOrnotResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Json using external Libarary "SBJson" or
if you are getting the responce in Soap Xml . parse your xml with [NSXmlParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/) 
example for NSXMLParser is [Parsing SOAP response with NSXMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599622/parsing-soap-response-with-nsxmlparser)

paste your json in the link to see the sequence of array and dictionaries
[Json Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and use the below code

```
let array : NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
```

In your json there is an Array and it has dictionaries so you got the array after `NSJSONSerialization` and you can access you Dictionary as

```
let dict : NSDictionary = array.firstObject as NSDictionary
```

Use XMLReader to parse your Soap XML a better and easy solution. 
https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader

use the code as following as i have used this pass your soapXML responce in string to this XMLReader and it will return you a NSDictionary

```
    var dict : NSDictionary = XMLReader.dictionaryForXMLString(serviceResponce as String, error: NSErrorPointer())
var jsonString : String = dict.objectForKey("soap:Envelope")?.objectForKey("soap:Body")?.objectForKey("checkloginOrnotResponse")?.objectForKey("checkloginOrnotResult") as String
```

Now you have JsonString and you can parse a string json as u want with library SBJson or any other and you will get your required result.

Comment: Can u provide the example , my Request code is this 
 NSString *soapBody=@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><checkloginOrnot xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><imeino>string</imeino></checkloginOrnot></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]]

Comment: [request setHTTPBody:[soapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"Post"];
    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/checkloginOrnot" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    
    
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

Comment: if you are getting the responce in Soap then . Parse the soap xml do it with NSXmlParser and then save the value of this tag"checkloginOrnotResult" in array

Comment: how to save that ? Please tell me.

Comment: if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSXMLParser class]]) {
            NSXMLParser *parser = (NSXMLParser *) responseObject;
            
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *dict=[XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser error:&error];
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@",dict);
            //NSLog(@"JSON: %@",dict[@"checkloginOrnotResult"]);

Comment: JSON: { "soap:Envelope" =     {  "soap:Body" =         {   checkloginOrnotResponse =             { checkloginOrnotResult =                 {
                    text = "[{\"loginstatus\":\"No\",\"userprofileid\":null,\"username\":null,\"usercompname\":null,\"mailverified\":false,\"ststusid\":30}]";
                };
                xmlns = "http://tempuri.org/";
            };
        };
        "xmlns:soap" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    };
}

Answer (score 0):

Getting Dictionary from JSON is quite simple:

```
jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseNSData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```